# C++: Global container not being modified

Tags: c++, containers, global

I have the following C++ code:

```
map<string, map<string, deque<Event> > > events;

int main(){
        //set up socket and stuff here (omitted for clarity)
        while(1){
                newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &client_len);
                if (newsockfd < 0)
                        error("ERROR on accept");

                pid = fork();
                if (pid < 0)
                        error("ERROR on event server fork");

                if (pid == 0){  //Child Process
                        close(sockfd);

                        //do stuff here
                        read_and_send_ack (newsockfd);
                        exit(0);
                }

                else //Parent Process
                        close(newsockfd);
}

void read_and_send_ack (int sockfd)
{
        // buffer is basically a string
        //do some non important stuff here, omitted for clarity
        event_received(buffer, &events);
}

void event_received(char* event_info, map<string, map<string, deque<Event> > >* events)
{
        Event event = Event(event_info);
        (*events)[string(event.device)][string(event.dev_id)].push_back(event);

        //print keys to test if events are being modified each turn
        for (map<string, map<string, deque<Event> > >::iterator it = events->begin(); it!=events->end(); ++it)
                cout << it->first;
}
```

I expect the global container "events" to be modified each time the while loop receives something to add to the container. But the change does not persist. As a result, whenever I print out the keys, only one key is in the container. What is going on? I thought all processes/threads can access the same global variable in C++.

Comment: Is `event_received` called at all? Also, it doesn't seem like a good idea to reuse names like that (`events` in this case). It will work as expected, but it's confusing when reading sources.

Comment: Do you expect the child process to modify the global variable `events` in the parent process?

Comment: @Angew: Ha! I guess you've nailed it down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

When the child process is created by `fork()`, it gets its own copy of the process state, *including global variables.*

If you want the parent and child process to communicate, you'll have to set up some form of channel for them to do so (such as a pipe, a file, shared memory or something similar).

Comment: I see. Will change my approach. THanks